# How to scale both X and y data in sklearn pipeline?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to scale both the X feature data and y output data in my sklearn pipeline. My code is as below, using grid search to calculate the optimum number of LVs using cross validation.

```
kfold = KFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = False) # Kfold
pipeline = Pipeline(steps = [('preprocessor',StandardScaler()),('model',PLSRegression()]) # Pipeline

param_grid = {'model__n_components':np.arange(1,10)} # param grid for no of components
  search = GridSearchCV(pipeline,param_grid, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error',cv = kfold, refit = True) # grid search CV using 5 fold CV, refitting best model with full dataset
  search.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain) # search through grid
```

Answer (score 2):

`Pipeline` objects are meant to apply a series of transformations to the features before feeding them to the final estimator along with the target values. As of now, you cannot transform the target values within such a pipeline.

At the moment, the canonical way to perform a transformation on the target for regression tasks is to use the `TransformedTargetRegressor`. From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html):

> Useful for applying a non-linear transformation to the target y in regression problems.

You can also pass the pipeline you defined in your question to a `TransformedTargetRegressor` object and specify a transformation or function which should be applied to the targets `y`. Here an example of how you would apply `StandardScaler`:

```py
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


pipeline = Pipeline(steps = [('preprocessor', StandardScaler()),('model',PLSRegression()])
estimator = TransformedTargetRegressor(estimator=pipeline, transformer=StandardScaler())
```

You can then pass this `estimator` object above to `GridSearchCV` for finding the best hyperparameters.

Comment: @gnashergnawer did this answer your question? If yes, please accept it and consider upvoting. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

In your pipeline, replace `PLSRegression()` with `TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=PLSRegression(), transformer=StandardScaler())`. That should combine the target transformer into the sklearn pipeline.